# How to add debug information when compiling with Java's Compiler API

Tags: java, compilation, java-6

What do I need to do to control whether my classes compiled with a [`JavaCompiler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) will include debug information or not?

I'm thinking it has something to do with the `getTask()`-method's `options` parameter, but I can't find any references on whether that assumption is correct to start with, and if so, what is the correct way to control that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could search further in the "options" argument of the getTask() method, which allows to pass options to the compiler; in your case it would be some "-g:none" option as detailed in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html
In JavaCompiler class there is a field to pass in the options 
-g is the one for debug information.